# Enemy sprite with a raycast ground check is flipping even when it shouldn't

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, raycasting

I have a 2D Sprite that patrols around a platform and is supposed to flip when it reaches the edge.

The way the flipping is implemented is through Raycasts. There are two Transforms, on the Left and Right bottom of the Sprite, that are used as the origin for a Ray with a direction downwards.

The code for the flipping is as below:

```cs
        foreach(Transform flipCheck in flipChecks)
        {
            //Flip when reach the edg of the ground
 
            if(!Physics2D.Raycast(flipCheck.position, Vector2.down, raycastLength, castLayerMask) && canFlip)
            {
                Flip();
                Ground = false;
            }
        } 
    }
}
        
//flip the scale of the character in order to turn around
void Flip()
{
    Debug.Log("Fliping");
    currentMoveDirection *= -1;
    //have flip cooldown 
    StartCoroutine(SetCanFlip());
}

//Flip cooldown
IEnumerator SetCanFlip()
{
    canFlip = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    canFlip = true;
}
```

The issue is that the flipping is happening too frequently, often in the middle of the platform.

It should be noted that the platform consists of multiple blocks, with a polygon collider 2D on each and a platform effector 2D component. The `layerMask` used is a custom layer called `ground`.

Comment: Can you please add some pictures to show the shape of the platform, the shape of the enemy, the location of the starting point of the ray detection? There are many possible causes, more details would be helpful.

Comment: There is also missing some code. When is this called (Update/ Coroutine)? What is `Ground` doing? And if you flip your sprite, why do you need two Raycasts? Can the sprite move backwards?

Comment: @Zibelas the line before Flip() are in Update(). I am not flipping the Sprite but the Direction the player is moving in.